# How to load list of files in commit into quickfix

Tags: quickfix, git

Using `git` how can I load the list of files in the current commit into Quickfix window?

Code Review didn't pass and I want to just fix them one by one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use the following function which has the advantage of not changing the state of your local git repo:

```
function! CommitQF(...)
    " Get the commit hash if it was specified
    let commit = a:0 == 0 ? '' : a:1

    " Get the result of git show in a list
    let flist = system('git show --name-only ' . commit . ' | tail -n +7')
    let flist = split(flist, '\n')

    " Create the dictionnaries used to populate the quickfix list
    let list = []
    for f in flist
        let dic = {'filename': f, "lnum": 1}
        call add(list, dic)
    endfor

    " Populate the qf list
    call setqflist(list)
endfunction
```

You can call it without argument or with a commit hash as argument (if no argument is specified, the last commit will be used):

```
call CommitQF("cc5b6a976fde8c9ee66387c91765feb202ba0124")
call CommitQF()
```

It will use the `git show` command with the `--name-only` argument to get the name of the files in the commit. The `tail -n +7` command removes the lines which are not a file name in the output of `git show`.

Then it will create a list of dictionnaries used to populate the quickfix list (see [`:h setqflist()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#setqflist%28%29) for more details about that).

You will need to use `:copen` to open the quicklist after calling the function (or you can add it to the function)

---

**Edit** Another possible approach (*and probably a better one*) using only built in features would be to use these settings:

```
set makeprg=git\ show\ --name-only\ $*\ \\\|\ tail\ -n\ +7
set efm+=%f
```

This way you can use `:make` (for the current commit) or `:make fff93a09` (to specify a commit).

The quickfix window will then contain the list of files and you'll be able to navigate to them.

(Of course you might want to create a mapping of something to switch between your usual `makeprg` and this one)

You can have a look at these help topics:

- [`:h errorformat`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/quickfix.txt.html#errorformat)
- [`:h 'makeprg'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27makeprg%27)

---

**Second edit** @PeterRincker and @LucHermitte made some really nice suggestions in the comments, many thanks to them.

You could use the following one liner:

```
command -nargs=? -bar Gshow call setqflist(map(systemlist("git show --pretty='' --name-only <args>"), '{"filename": v:val, "lnum": 1}'))
```

To create a command `:Gshow` which takes a commit hash as an optionnal argument and populate the quickfix list.

Comment: Can also use `git show --pretty='' --name-only <revision>` to remove the commit message information and only show filenames

Comment: I would have used `map(copy(flist), '{"filename": v:val, "lnum": 1}')` instead of the `:for` loop -- it's always faster, but also much less annoying to debug.

Comment: With @LucHermitte suggestions this could easily be a one liner: `command -nargs=? -bar Gshow call setqflist(map(systemlist("git show --pretty='' --name-only <args>"), '{"filename": v:val, "lnum": 1}'))`

Comment: Thank you both for your suggestion it is indeed much more efficient than my original answer.

Comment: Is there a plug-in that does that?

Comment: @firedev see the last comment of peter rincker and my second edit: it's only one line to add to your vimrc, you don't need a plugin.

Answer (score 5):

#### Plugin Fugitive v3.2 (Jan 2020)

[vim-fugitive](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive) has added new commands since the OP raised this question which can do exactly what the OP has asked.

Now you can call

```
:Git difftool
```

or the abbreviated version

```
:G difft[tab complete]
```

This loads all changesets into the quickfix list. If files have several changes, they occur several times in the quickfix list. I like this. However, if you prefer to have only each file once, run

```
 :G difftool --name-only
```

Answer (score 5):

Here are two related approaches. Both use `git-*` scripts; if you put them on your `PATH`, you can invoke them as if they were subcommands of git.

### Use the contrib script [`git-jump`](https://github.com/git/git/tree/master/contrib/git-jump)

The `git-jump` script provides a handy way to load diff hunks, grep results, or whitespace errors into an editor that supports quickfix formats.

Since `git jump diff` forwards its arguments to diff, and since you’re interested in the last commit, you can do

```
git jump diff @^ @
```

### Use my [`git-ed`](https://github.com/benknoble/Dotfiles/blob/master/links/bin/git-ed) script

My `git-ed` script was written before I knew about `git-jump`. I used it a lot then (less now). It’s only purpose is to open in an editor the changed files (either currently, in a single commit, or in a range of commits). So simply invoke

```
git ed @
```

And use the argument list.

Comment: Installation note: You can't add `/usr/share/doc/git/contrib/git-jump` to your path because git doesn't ship git-jump as executable. You'll have to copy git-jump into your own bin directory.

Comment: @idbrii For me the path was `/usr/local/share/git-core/contrib/git-jump`, which *does* ship executable (or at least, for me it did). If you're under `doc`, you may not have the right path? The script in the repo has executable permissions, so unless whatever you used to install git removed them, it should retain them

Answer (score 3):

The only thing that comes to mind is

```
git reset --soft head~1
```

That would "uncommit" the files, and then browse them in Preview window using `vim-fugitive` `:Gtatus` command. Not exactly Quickfix, but it's readable, stores your position and you can stage/unstage from there.

Answer (score 3):

Add this to your `.vimrc` file and you're all set up. This adds files from `git diff` to the `quick fix` list:

```
let s:git_status_dictionary = {
            \ "A": "Added",
            \ "B": "Broken",
            \ "C": "Copied",
            \ "D": "Deleted",
            \ "M": "Modified",
            \ "R": "Renamed",
            \ "T": "Changed",
            \ "U": "Unmerged",
            \ "X": "Unknown"
            \ }
function! s:get_diff_files()
  let list = map(split(system(
              \ 'git diff --name-status HEAD'), '\n'),
              \ '{"filename":matchstr(v:val, "\\S\\+$"),"text":s:git_status_dictionary[matchstr(v:val, "^\\w")]}'
              \ )
  call setqflist(list)
  copen
endfunction

command! -nargs=0 DiffRev call s:get_diff_files()
```

[Credits](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive/issues/132#issuecomment-290644034):  slightly edited

Answer (score 0):

**Fastest way to add diff hunks to quickfix**

Quickfix is very handy feature. It is even has it's own format definition, but it is not easy expand. I found more easy to reformat diff to format of compilation errors: "$file:$line:$message". Reformatting works as standalone filter function. It combination with vim option -q it very easy to use and resuse, no need to additional installations and configutaions:

Here is my the shortest solution.

```
diff_to_quickfix()
{
     perl -ne '/^\+\+\+ (.+)/ && { $f="$1"};/@@.*\+(\d+)/ && print "$f:$1:$_\n"'
}

vim -q <(git show -U0 --no-prefix | diff_to_quickfix)


vim -q <(git diff -U0 --no-prefix | diff_to_quickfix)
```